# add icons to list grouper in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list with different groups, can we just add icons to these groups and what is the possible way to it?
I want to add the icons also on the group heading along with the name.

Comment: [http://whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score -1):

What's the problem?
Add to the group property your image:

```
var myModel = Ext.define(model, {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'title', 'group', 'groupOrder'
        ]
    }
});    
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: myModel,
    grouper: {
        property: 'group',
        sortProperty: 'groupOrder'
    },
    data:[{title:'Title', group: '<img src="myImgSrc"> MyGroupTitle', groupOrder:0}]
});
```